# Iterating over values from fixed sum, in MatLab

Tags: matlab, combinatorics, loops

Let's say I have n marbles, and each can be one of 8 possible colors.  I want to iterate over all possible values of color combinations of the marbles.  How can I do this in MatLab?

For example, if n = 2, then I want to iterate through:

2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0

etc.

EDIT:

This is what some pseudocode would look like, but as you can see it's very sloppy.  I'm interested in a more concise way of doing this, and one that doesn't need that if statement...

```
for i8 = 0:1:n
    for i7 = 0:1:n - i8
        for i6 = 0:1:n - i8 - i7
            for i5 = 0:1:n - i8 - i7 - i6
                for i4 = 0:1:n - i8 - i7 - i6 - i5
                    for i3 = 0:1:n - i8 - i7 - i6 - i5 - i4
                        for i2 = 0:1:n - i8 - i7 - i6 - i5 - i4 - i3
                            for i1 = 0:1:n - i8 - i7 - i6 - i5 - i4 - i3 - i2
                                if i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5 + i6 + i7 + i8 == n
                                    i = [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8]
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution (the code was tested in GNU/Octave, it should work in Matlab as well).
This code is derived from [Octave-Forge multinom_exp.m](http://octave.sourceforge.net/specfun/function/multinom_exp.html)

```
function conf = marbin (nmar,nbin)
%% Returns the position of nmar in nbis, allowing the marbles to be in the same bin.

%% This is standard stars and bars.
 numsymbols = nbin+nmar-1;
 stars = nchoosek (1:numsymbols, nmar);

%% Star labels minus their consecutive position becomes their index
%% position!
 idx = bsxfun (@minus, stars, [0:nmar-1]);

%% Manipulate indices into the proper shape for accumarray.
 nr = size (idx, 1);
 a = repmat ([1:nr], nmar, 1);
 b = idx';
 conf = [a(:), b(:)];
 conf = accumarray (conf, 1);
```

Comment: Hello jamaicaworm, this code works for arbitrary number of colors and marbles. It is also vectorized and you will not have memory problems. The output is formated exactly in the way you need. What is the problem, why you do not test it?

Comment: It is using the properties of the [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(probability)) method to compute the position of the marbles (each bin has a color state associated with it). That's it, the rest is to produce the output format you wanted. If you look at the multinom_exp function in GNU/Octave you will see that JordiGH was the guy who come with the idea. I couldn't find much explanations in the web, but you could get the book by Feller to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is easier is you think of the states of the marbles, rather than the states of the colors.  Then convert from marble states to color states as needed.  For example, if thinking about an ordered list of all possible marble states, you could create function that looks like this (using all zeros as an "all done" flag):

```
function state = nextmarblestate(state, nMarbles, nColors)
%Increment the marble state by 1

%Add one to the last marble
state(end) = state(end)+1;

%Propogate change towards the first marble as colors overflow
for ixCurrent = nMarbles:-1:2
    if state(ixCurrent) > nColors;
        state(ixCurrent) = 1;
        state(ixCurrent-1) = state(ixCurrent-1)+1;
    else
        return;
    end
end

%Check to see if we are done (reset to 0)
if state(1) > nColors
    state = zeros(1,nMarbles);
end
```

Then you can write a quick loop to go through all of the marble states like this:

```
nMarbles = 2;
nColors = 8;

marblestate = ones(1,nMarbles);
while sum(marblestate)>0
    disp(['Marblestate = [' num2str(marblestate) ']'])
    marblestate = nextmarblestate(marblestate, nMarbles, nColors);
end
```

Or, to get the result you wanted, write a conversion from marble state to color state, like this (sorry for the terseness here, this could be expanded to a prettier version):

```
marbleState2colorState = @(marblestate) arrayfun(@(color)sum(marblestate==color), 1:nColors);
```

And then using that conversion function, expand the while loop above like so:

```
marblestate = ones(1,nMarbles);
while sum(marblestate)>0
    disp(['Marblestate = [' num2str(marblestate) '],  Colorstate = [' num2str(marbleState2colorState(marblestate)) ']'])
    marblestate = nextmarblestate(marblestate, nMarbles, nColors);
end
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Marblestate = [1  1],  Colorstate = [2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [1  2],  Colorstate = [1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [1  3],  Colorstate = [1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [1  4],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [1  5],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [1  6],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [1  7],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [1  8],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [2  1],  Colorstate = [1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [2  2],  Colorstate = [0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [2  3],  Colorstate = [0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [2  4],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [2  5],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [2  6],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [2  7],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [2  8],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [3  1],  Colorstate = [1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [3  2],  Colorstate = [0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [3  3],  Colorstate = [0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [3  4],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [3  5],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [3  6],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [3  7],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [3  8],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [4  1],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [4  2],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [4  3],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [4  4],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [4  5],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [4  6],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [4  7],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [4  8],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [5  1],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [5  2],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [5  3],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [5  4],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [5  5],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0]
Marblestate = [5  6],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [5  7],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [5  8],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [6  1],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [6  2],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [6  3],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [6  4],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [6  5],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0]
Marblestate = [6  6],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0]
Marblestate = [6  7],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0]
Marblestate = [6  8],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1]
Marblestate = [7  1],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [7  2],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [7  3],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [7  4],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [7  5],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0]
Marblestate = [7  6],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0]
Marblestate = [7  7],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0]
Marblestate = [7  8],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1]
Marblestate = [8  1],  Colorstate = [1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [8  2],  Colorstate = [0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [8  3],  Colorstate = [0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [8  4],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [8  5],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1]
Marblestate = [8  6],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1]
Marblestate = [8  7],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1]
Marblestate = [8  8],  Colorstate = [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 marbles, and each can be one of 8 possible colors, then this will suffice:

```
>> dec2base(0:63,8)
ans =
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
```

Note that it stores the information in a different way than you did, but the same information is there. It should be easy enough to convert to your form if you needed that.

Comment: Right, this just iterates over 8^n, doesn't it?  How do I convert the format in my question (i.e., 8-vectors whose sum is n)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following code snippet works for the n = 2 case.

This was written in Octave as I don't have access to Matlab at present.

I have tested with various low values of colours (2,3,4,5,6 and 8) against hand generated results.

```
colours = 4;
marbles = 2;

for i=1:colours
   a = zeros(1,colours);
   a(i) = marbles
   for j=i:colours-1
      a(j) = a(j) -1;
      a(j+1) = a(j+1)+1  
   endfor
endfor
```

I am still working on the code snippet for the general case of for any number of colours and any number of marbles.

Comment: Thanks!  If you could get this to work for any n, that would be great.  (As of now, it doesn't work, since for n=3 for example it doesn't let the possiblity of having something like 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0.)

Answer (score 2):

```
nc = 8;    % number colors
nm = 2;    % number marbles

% For now let marbles be unique. There are then nc^nm assignments of
% marbles to colors
nmc = nc^nm;

% Enumerate the assignments of marbles to colors: i.e., sub{k} is a row
% array giving the color of marble k for each of the nmc assignments
[sub{1:nm,1}] = ind2sub(nc*ones(1,nm),1:nmc);

% We'll use accumarray to map the marble color assignments in sub to number
% of marbles of each color
% Bring sub into form required for application of accumarray
s = mat2cell(cell2mat(sub),nm,ones(nmc,1));

% apply accumarray to each assignement of colors to marbles
a = cellfun(@(c)accumarray(c,1,[nc,1]),s,'UniformOutput',false);

% Each element of a is a column vector giving the number of marbles of each
% color. We want row vectors, and we want only the unique rows
a = unique(cell2mat(a)','rows'); 

% a is as desired.
```

Comment: This is great, but MatLab runs out of memory for n > 9.  I'm looking to do this iteration for something like n = 500, so in order to not run out of memory, I don't want to store every possible combination in an array--I just need to iterate through each possible combination (so I can perform a simple operation for each one).